# Multi step vertical form using progress bar I have horizontal form so convert vertical model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have troubling with adding this vertical multi step form, I would be very much glad if any one can help me in this. Our horizontal link https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/yNxMeJ same look convert vertical steps.

```css
.steps {
        width: 675px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
    }
     fieldset {
      background: white;
      border: 0 none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      box-shadow: 0 17px 41px -21px rgb(0, 0, 
    .steps0);
      padding: 20px 30px;
      border-top: 9px solid #7B1FA2;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 10%;
      
      /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="info">
      <h1>Fundraising Grader</h1>
      <span>
        Made with
        <i class="fa fa-beer"></i>
        by
        <a href="http://www.idesignradthings.com">Ty Stelmach</a>
        <div class="spoilers">
          An app created to score your nonprofit's fundraising technique.</a> 
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal -info -->
    <div class="container">
    <div id="modal-3" class="modal" data-modal-effect="slide-top">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Score Index</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Getting the most out of your data</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis. Nunc ullamcorper bibendum diam, vitae tempus dolor hendrerit iaculis. Phasellus tellus elit, feugiat vel mi et, euismod varius augue. Nulla a porttitor sapien. Donec vestibulum ac nisl sed bibendum. Praesent neque ipsum, commodo eget venenatis vel, tempus sit amet ante. Curabitur vel odio eget urna dapibus imperdiet sit amet eget felis. Vestibulum eros velit, posuere a metus eget, aliquam euismod purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button modal-close" value="Got it!">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <form class="steps" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="">
      <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">User Information</li>
        <li>Aquisition</li>
        <li>Cultivation</li>
        <li>Cultivation2</li>
        <li>Retention</li>
      </ul>



      <!-- USER INFORMATION FIELD SET --> 
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Basic Information</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We just need some basic information to begin your scoring</h3>
        <!-- Begin What's Your First Name Field -->
            <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your First Name? *</label>

              <input id="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983" name="firstname" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your first name" >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
        <!-- End What's Your First Name Field -->

        <!-- Begin What's Your Email Field -->
            <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your E-mail Address? *</label>

              <input id="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid email address." >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
        <!-- End What's Your Email Field -->

        <!-- Begin Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
            <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field hs_total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What's the Total Number of Constituents in your Database? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number" >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

        <!-- End Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
        <input type="button" data-page="1" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3"><i class="question-log fa fa-question-circle"></i> What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- ACQUISITION FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Acquisition of Donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How have you been doing in acquiring donors?</h3>
          <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-1">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1 total_number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_donors_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-2">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2 total_number_of_donors_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_donors_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_donor_percent_change field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change total_donor_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Total Donors Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_donor_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- Cultivation FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Cultivation and Nurturing your Donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How have you been nurturing donors to get better donations?</h3>
          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size in Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1 average_gift_size_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1 average_gift_size_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">What was your average gift size in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size in Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size in Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-2">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-2 average_gift_size_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">What was your average gift size in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size in Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size Perchent Change Field -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_average_gift_size_percent_change field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--percent-change1">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change1 average_gift_size_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">Average Gift Size Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change1" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size Perchent Change Field -->
        <input type="button" data-page="3" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="3" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- Cultivation2 FIELD SET --> 
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Total Cultivation in Donation</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Let's talk about your donations as a whole</h3>
                  <!-- Begin Total Giving In Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-3 hs_total_giving_in_year_1 field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-3 total_giving_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">What was your total giving in Year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-3" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Total Giving In Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Total Giving In Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_giving_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-4"> 
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-4 total_giving_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">What was your total giving in Year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-4" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
            <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            
            <!-- End Total Giving In Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size Percent Change Field 2 -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_giving_percent_change field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--percent-change2">

              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change2 total_giving_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">Average Gift Size Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change2" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size Percent Change Field 2 -->
        <input type="button" data-page="4" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="4" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- RETENTION FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Retention of your donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How long can you keep your donors and their donations?</h3>
            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 Field -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What was your total number of donors who gave in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-retention-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="number_of_donors_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 Field-->


            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 and Year 2 Field -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-retention--amount-2 hs_number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2 field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-2 number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What was your total number of donors who gave in year 1 that also gave in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-retention-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 and Year 2 Field -->

            <!-- Begin Retention Rate Percent -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-retention--percent-change field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-retention-percent-change">Retention Rate</label>

             <input id="edit-submitted-retention-percent-change" class="form-text hs-input" name="retention_rate_percent" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
              
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>

            <!-- End Retention Rate Percent -->


            <!-- Begin Final Calc -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_fundraising_400_index field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-final-grade--grade">

              <label for=" fundraising_400_index-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Fundraising 400 Index Score</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-final-grade-grade" class="form-text hs-input" name="fundraising_400_index" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
              </div>
            <!-- End Final Calc -->
        <input type="button" data-page="5" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input id="submit" class="hs-button primary large action-button next" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
    </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">It's on the way!</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Thank you for trying out our marketing grader, please go check your email for your fundraising report card and some helpful tips to improve it!</h3>
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>
```

I just want to know how to link this vertical a multi step form. I tried several times, but did not work. above link code is working horizontal but when I include multi step form with fieldsets it doesn't work. This is a project for school.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this codepen...I hope it solves your problem
https://codepen.io/mgkrish/pen/QmbxYZ

```css
.steps {
        width: 675px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
    }
     fieldset {
      background: white;
      border: 0 none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      box-shadow: 0 17px 41px -21px rgb(0, 0, 
    .steps0);
      padding: 20px 30px;
      border-top: 9px solid #7B1FA2;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 10%;
      
      /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="info">
      <h1>Fundraising Grader</h1>
      <span>
        Made with
        <i class="fa fa-beer"></i>
        by
        <a href="http://www.idesignradthings.com">Ty Stelmach</a>
        <div class="spoilers">
          An app created to score your nonprofit's fundraising technique.</a> 
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal -info -->
    <div class="container">
    <div id="modal-3" class="modal" data-modal-effect="slide-top">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Score Index</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Getting the most out of your data</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis. Nunc ullamcorper bibendum diam, vitae tempus dolor hendrerit iaculis. Phasellus tellus elit, feugiat vel mi et, euismod varius augue. Nulla a porttitor sapien. Donec vestibulum ac nisl sed bibendum. Praesent neque ipsum, commodo eget venenatis vel, tempus sit amet ante. Curabitur vel odio eget urna dapibus imperdiet sit amet eget felis. Vestibulum eros velit, posuere a metus eget, aliquam euismod purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button modal-close" value="Got it!">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <form class="steps" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="">
      <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">User Information</li>
        <li>Aquisition</li>
        <li>Cultivation</li>
        <li>Cultivation2</li>
        <li>Retention</li>
      </ul>



      <!-- USER INFORMATION FIELD SET --> 
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Basic Information</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We just need some basic information to begin your scoring</h3>
        <!-- Begin What's Your First Name Field -->
            <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your First Name? *</label>

              <input id="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983" name="firstname" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your first name" >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
        <!-- End What's Your First Name Field -->

        <!-- Begin What's Your Email Field -->
            <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your E-mail Address? *</label>

              <input id="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid email address." >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
        <!-- End What's Your Email Field -->

        <!-- Begin Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
            <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field hs_total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What's the Total Number of Constituents in your Database? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number" >
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

        <!-- End Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
        <input type="button" data-page="1" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3"><i class="question-log fa fa-question-circle"></i> What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- ACQUISITION FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Acquisition of Donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How have you been doing in acquiring donors?</h3>
          <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-1">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1 total_number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_donors_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-2">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2 total_number_of_donors_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_number_of_donors_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_donor_percent_change field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change total_donor_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Total Donors Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_donor_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- Cultivation FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Cultivation and Nurturing your Donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How have you been nurturing donors to get better donations?</h3>
          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size in Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1 average_gift_size_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1 average_gift_size_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">What was your average gift size in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size in Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size in Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_average_gift_size_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-2">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-2 average_gift_size_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">What was your average gift size in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size in Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size Perchent Change Field -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_average_gift_size_percent_change field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--percent-change1">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change1 average_gift_size_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_3256">Average Gift Size Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change1" class="form-text hs-input" name="average_gift_size_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size Perchent Change Field -->
        <input type="button" data-page="3" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="3" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- Cultivation2 FIELD SET --> 
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Total Cultivation in Donation</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Let's talk about your donations as a whole</h3>
                  <!-- Begin Total Giving In Year 1 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-3 hs_total_giving_in_year_1 field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-3 total_giving_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">What was your total giving in Year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-3" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <!-- End Total Giving In Year 1 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Total Giving In Year 2 Field -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_giving_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--amount-4"> 
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-4 total_giving_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">What was your total giving in Year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-amount-4" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
            <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            
            <!-- End Total Giving In Year 2 Field -->

          <!-- Begin Average Gift Size Percent Change Field 2 -->
          <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
            <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_giving_percent_change field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-cultivation--percent-change2">

              <label for=" edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change2 total_giving_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_4902">Average Gift Size Percent Change</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-cultivation-percent-change2" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_giving_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
            <!-- End Average Gift Size Percent Change Field 2 -->
        <input type="button" data-page="4" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="4" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>



      <!-- RETENTION FIELD SET -->  
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Retention of your donors</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How long can you keep your donors and their donations?</h3>
            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 Field -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What was your total number of donors who gave in year 1? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-retention-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="number_of_donors_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 Field-->


            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 and Year 2 Field -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-retention--amount-2 hs_number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2 field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-2 number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What was your total number of donors who gave in year 1 that also gave in year 2? *</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-retention-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="number_of_year_1_donors_who_also_gave_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
              
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors Who Gave in Year 1 and Year 2 Field -->

            <!-- Begin Retention Rate Percent -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-retention--percent-change field hs-form-field">
            
              <label for="edit-submitted-retention-percent-change">Retention Rate</label>

             <input id="edit-submitted-retention-percent-change" class="form-text hs-input" name="retention_rate_percent" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
              
              <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                  <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              </span>
              </div>

            <!-- End Retention Rate Percent -->


            <!-- Begin Final Calc -->
              <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_fundraising_400_index field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-final-grade--grade">

              <label for=" fundraising_400_index-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Fundraising 400 Index Score</label>

              <input id="edit-submitted-final-grade-grade" class="form-text hs-input" name="fundraising_400_index" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="0">
              </div>
            <!-- End Final Calc -->
        <input type="button" data-page="5" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input id="submit" class="hs-button primary large action-button next" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
    </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">It's on the way!</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Thank you for trying out our marketing grader, please go check your email for your fundraising report card and some helpful tips to improve it!</h3>
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
      </fieldset>
```